# Grabbing Python source code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a project which requires unmodified/uncompiled/"vanilla" version of the source of Python version 3.3 alpha 0. From Python website, the least I can get is [Python 3.3.0](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.3.0/). Can anybody point me to the 3.3 alpha 0 version of Python source code?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it from the Python [repository](https://hg.python.org).

I didn't see v3.3.0a0, the earliest C Python being [v3.3.0a1](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/f1a9a6505731).